# polymer databinding performence

Tags: polymer, btle

I am trying to make an app that reads data from a device over btle and displays this data in a streaming graph. I want to do this with use of polymer. It would be nice to shield the complexity of btle.
To have a html tag for btle that displays a BTLE icon and double click will connect to the device. But ones it is connected I want the (notify)data to connect to my graph. When I look at examples of polymer data binding it only binds to very slow data sources like an input field. So my question is can this be done (2KB/sec) with Polymer or is it to slow and should I keep the data out of Polymer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance of data-binding has to do with how many bindings there are, and the expense of whatever side-effects you trigger, not data-size or transfer speeds.

Generally anything measured in *seconds* is much slower than the kind of throughput we worry about in Polymer.